# batch random number between 5 digit and 6 digit numbers

Tags: batch-file, random, numbers

Simple as getting a random number from 10000 to 999999
I am not sure how to do this and most instructions didn't work.
I'm fairly new to batch.

Comment: This is one of those things where you're going to kick yourself when you see how it's done. What code, specifically, have you tried already? You were probably really close.

Comment: This create a random number with smooth distribution between 10000 and 999563: `set /A %random% * %random% / 1085 + 10000`

Comment: @Aacini That's not a smooth distribution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although you can use `%RANDOM%` in a batch file to get a random number, it will be between 0 and 32767.

The traditional approach of `%RANDOM% * n / 32767` won't give you a smooth distribution for n = 999999-10000 = 989999 ... it will cover the range, but there will be big gaps.

Similarly, you can't just add lots of calls to `%RANDOM%` together because the sum of the random values is [not itself uniformly distributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370228/).

I recommend switching to PowerShell 2.0, where you will be able to use the [`Get-Random` Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730929.aspx) across the full range of integers. Either that, or write a simple program in another language just to generate the random number, and then call it from your batch file.

**Edit:**

You can do this to get a random number between 10000 and 999999:

```
set /a rnd=(((%random% * 32768) + %random%) %%990000) + 10000
```

It's not perfectly uniform, but may be good enough for your purposes.

Given the question title, perhaps you're actually looking for a number between 100000 and 999999 (i.e. 5 or 6 digits). In this case you could use this:

```
set /a rnd=(((%random% * 32768) + %random%) %%900000) + 100000
```

Unlike the approach using addition, this uses two random numbers (one for the higher-order bits and one for the lower-order bits), which should give a uniform distribution between 0 and 1073741823; the non-uniformity comes from the wrap-around you get from the modulus (`%%`) operation. You could avoid this, too, if you used a loop and rejected any candidate random values above 1073700000 (=900000 * 1193).

Comment: So the conclusion of your "answer" is that this can not be done in a Batch file? You could said that in a comment...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
:: Generate linear random number into variable %1
:: length is %2 digits
:: maxvalue %3 (optional. string of %2 9s if omitted)
:: minval %4 (optional, 0 if omitted)
:: to set minval but not maxval, use "" as %3
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET $digits=%2
SET $maxval=%~3
SET $minval=%4
IF NOT DEFINED $digits GOTO :EOF
IF DEFINED $maxval GOTO maxvalset
:maxvallp
SET "$maxval=9%$maxval%"
IF "!$maxval:~%2!"=="" GOTO maxvallp
SET "$maxval=%$maxval:~1%"

:maxvalset
IF NOT DEFINED $minval SET /a minval=0
:minvallp
SET "$minval=0%$minval%"
IF "!$minval:~%2!"=="" GOTO minvallp
SET "$minval=%$minval:~1%"

:minvalset
SET "$chosen="
SET /a $count=%2

:getdigit
SET /a $digit=%RANDOM%
IF %$digit% gtr 32759 GOTO getdigit
SET /a $digit=%$digit:~-1%

SET "$chosen=%$chosen%%$digit%"
SET /a $count-=1
IF %$count% gtr 0 GOTO getdigit

IF "%$chosen%" gtr "%$maxval%" GOTO minvalset
IF "%$chosen%" lss "%$minval%" GOTO minvalset

:slzlp
IF %$chosen:~0,1%==0 IF %$chosen% neq 0 SET "$chosen=%$chosen:~1%"&GOTO slzlp

endlocal&set "%1=%$chosen%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a routine that will generate a random number with linear distribution of any length with maximum and minimum.

Its use expects some intelligence on the part of the user. Sure - asking for a number between 0 and 99 then adding 1 will be a whole lot faster than asking for a number between 1 and 100. It's also not bullet-proof and assumes the parameters with which it is provided are valid.

Each step is trivial - the variable names and labels should provide appropriate clues to their purpose. In essence, a string of random digits of the appropriate length is built and discarded if out-of-range. The magic number `32759` is chosen to make sure that the random number chosen as a basis for the digits generated are 0..32759 which will yield a linear distribution mod 10 assuming the random number generator is linear.